# Removing hiatus in x-axis data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

I have a bunch of time series data for a paleofire record I'm working on. The age depth model has a large hiatus in the middle, giving me an x-axis of 0-20,000 years, nothing for 80,000 years, then 100,000 to 145,000 years. I want to plot all the data together using geom_line, but when I do there's a long flat line connecting the two "groups", which bunches them up on the left and right, with most of the graph taken up by the long flat line. Is there a function of ggplot or another package that allows me to truncate(is that the right word?) the x-axis to remove the 80,000 year hiatus and have the two data parts sitting next to each other, perhaps with a squiggly line to indicate a cut? I've attached the code I used. I'd attach an image of the plot but I don't seem to be allowed to for some reason...

Thanks!

Mark

```
  CIRange <- ggplot(data = LC2AllDepth, mapping = aes(x = Age, y = Range, color = Treatment))+
    geom_line()+
    theme(axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(color = 'black'),
          axis.line.y.left   = element_line(color = 'black'),
          axis.line.y.right  = element_line(color = 'black'),
          axis.text.y.right  = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(),
          panel.border       = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank())+
    labs(x="Depth cm")+
    labs(y = "Range of CI")+ 
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 15), axis.title = element_text(size = 15))
  
  CIRange
```

[image: Current output]

Comment: I would use two facets.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches. First is to facet based on an added variable. Second is to manually map the later values to something closure to the earlier data, and then apply the same adjustment to the axis.

```
fake <- data.frame(Age = c(1E3*(0:20), 1E3*(100:145)),
                   Range = 1:67 * runif(67))


library(dplyr)
fake %>%
  mutate(era = if_else(Age < 1E5, "early", "later")) %>%
  mutate(Age_adj = Age - if_else(era == "later", 7E4, 90)) -> fake2
  

ggplot(fake2, aes(Age, Range)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~era, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(fake2, aes(Age_adj, Range, group = era)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1E4*(0:8), labels = scales::comma(1E4*c(0:2, 10:15)))
```

[image]